# What happens to threads when exec() is called?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, exec

I am taking an OS class and trying to wrap my head around this question, any help would be appreciated:

Consider a multi-threaded process with 10 threads. Thread 3 invokes an execlp() system call. Describe what will happen to each of the threads.

My understanding of exec() is that is replaces the current process with a new one, and it's main difference from fork() is that fork() creates a clone and you end up with duplicates.

So if exec() replaces the current process, would it kill the threads of the old process and replace them with the new one? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> exec()...replaces the current process with a new one.

Actually, it's still the same process after calling exec, and that's important because the parent process may still need to communicate with it, signal it, etc. What exec does is, it *guts* the process—wipes out all of it's virtual memory, resets all of its signal handlers, unlocks locks, closes *some* open files, etc. ([See here for more](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html))—and then it loads a new program into the existing process and starts executing it.

> would it kill the threads of the old process...?

[`man 2 execve`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) says, "All threads other than the calling thread are destroyed during
an execve().  Mutexes, condition variables, and other pthreads
objects are not preserved."